# Validate attribute for multiple values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

In my model, I would like to add a validation to check if my attribute presents both of its values (e.g., one of the record has its value `ValueA` and another record has its value `ValueB`-those being the only possibilities, and it needs to have at least one or both of them).

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try out this

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  VALID_VALUES = ['Value1', 'Value2']

  with_options presence: true do
    validates :your_field, inclusion: { in: VALID_VALUES, allow_blank: true }
  end

end
```